# Emacs command to evaluate a scheme expression in the buffer and show the result pasted in the buffer

Tags: emacs, clojure, scheme

I am basically looking for the Scheme equivalent of C-u C-x C-e in the clojure/nrepl mode, or C-c C-p.

I want a C-x C-e that prints the output to the buffer as opposed to just in the repl.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(require 'cmuscheme)
(setq scheme-program-name "/usr/local/<path-to-a-scheme>")
```

then within a Scheme file, in the Scheme Major Mode, there should be a 'Scheme' menu that shows all the key bindings.  To 'Evaluate Last S Expression' you'll use C-x C-e.  The result will not be in the Scheme file's source, it will be in the  *scheme* buffer running the inferior Scheme.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'd like is precisely for the result to be pasted in the source not `*scheme*`. I need this for a live coding.